# Problem with LINQ - necessary to add reference to unneeded library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, compiler-construction, extension-methods

I have a following issue. I have a solution that contains about 40 projects.
There is a project A that references project B that references project C. There isn't any code in project A that uses classes from project C. However, if I use any LINQ extension method in any code, e.g.:

```
var r = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Where(a => a > 1);
```

I get compiler error:

> somefile.cs(70,13): error CS0012: The type 'XXX' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Project C assembly name, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx'.

The error is on the line that uses linq extension method.

I'm using VS2010, .NET 3.5.

**Update:** It happens with every extension method. I have created a class in the same file, that looks like this:

```
public static class SomeClass
{
    public static int[] Test(this int[] a)
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

And then I write this code and compilation breaks with same error:

```
new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Test();
```

**Update2:** Ok, I found out what causes the error. But I don't know why. Following code causes error:

```
using System.Linq;
using B;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class A
    {
        public void M()
        {
            var c = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }.Where(s => s != null);
        }
    }
}
```

But if I remove using B (I'm stil following the names from my description that A references B, B references C) it compiles.
This is the ONLY code in project A. It compiles if I remove usage of extension method or if I remove "using B" as I said before.

**Update3:**

First of all, thanks for all your suggestions.
The smallest example I can come up with is the following. I created a new project, csproj looks like this (nothing has been changed, only C project name and C project guid):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{B649AB2C-926A-4AD1-B7E3-5A29AE1E9CC2}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>ClassLibraryTest</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ClassLibraryTest</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\C.csproj">
      <Project>{55AFFA2D-63E0-4BA9-XXXX-B70E6A936F5E}</Project>
      <Name>C</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Class1.cs contains following code:

```
using C;

namespace TestApp
{
    public static class Ext
    {
        public static void M213dsacxvz(this string[] a)
        {
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public void B()
        {
            new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }.M213dsacxvz();
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler error I get is as follows:

> D:\xxx\Class1.cs(16,13): error CS0012: The type 'xxx' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'xxx, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx'.

If I remove `using C;` it compiles just fine.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: That exact line of code? Or a line of code using a type from project B?

Comment: The exact line. It could even the line with in as in my example. Any usage of linq breaks compilation.

Comment: what type is a? (Maybe it is defined in the C project.)

Comment: @empi: Can you come up with a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem? It would be really helpful if we could reproduce this...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Unfortunately, I cannot. It is a large commercial project and I have never had such problem with any other project.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to close visual studio and restart it.

Comment: @Hogan: It happens on multiple machines and is fully reproducible using this VS solution.

Comment: You have some extension methods that take ints? Try changing your example to use a class of your own making instead of int. onother possibility is that some class has implicit conversion to/from int and C# gets confused which one you want.

Comment: @empi: I wasn't suggesting that you post your actual project. Take a copy of the real thing, and cut out swathes of it until you've either worked out what's causing it, or you've got a tiny example which shows the problem. You shouldn't need to post any commercially-sensitive code at all.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I updated the example.

Comment: @Pasi Savolainen: no, that's not the case with int - I've given identical problem with string.

Comment: What .NET framework is each project targeted for?

Comment: @Ilya Kogan: A - .NET 3.5 Class Library, B - .NET 3.5 Class Library, C - .NET 2.0 - it's an external library that is delivered by 3rd party

Comment: Does it make any difference if you set the references to B and C to "specific version"?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the type `XXX` (from the compiler error)?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Complete example in my answer.

Comment: @Jeff Sternal: the type xxx from project C is a base class for most classes defined in project C. Project C defines classes used in communication between different systems. It doesn't have ANY logic in there, it defines only structure of DTO objects.

Comment: @Can Gencer: Setting specific version on reference from project B to project C doesn't change anything. Project A references B as another project in same solution so I cannot set specific version.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I cannot create better example than the one in UPDATE3

Comment: @empi: You certainly could, given that you haven't shown any of the code from B or C. Fortunately, Rick has come up with a *genuinely* complete example - see his answer for what I was looking for.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Rick mentioned that if he changes method name he doesn't get compiler error - that's not my case. This happens only with project B. If I create another project D, D references C and A references D, and then I add using D as first line in Class1.cs this doesn't happen. It happens only with that particular project - B.

Comment: @empi: But it clearly depends on what's in A and C as well. You haven't given us a *complete* example, which is what we need.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: project A in update 3 is complete. It contains only Class1.cs, you can see csproj file and the problem still occurs. I am not able to create some fake projects B and C that cause error (it's not that I don't want to- I just cannot create another project that would cause that error). I know that my description may contain too few information to answer my question, but I tried my best to give as much information as possible. However,you must admit that this is really weird behavior that adding using directive forces user to add another project reference when extension method is used.

Comment: @empi: Yes, Project A is complete - but that's not enough. It's odd, but Rick's example is pretty compelling. You should be able to reduce your situation to the same thing. As I said, rather than starting with a *new* solution, take a copy of your existing one and remove bits from that until you've found out what's required.

Comment: @empi, you'll need to give us `B` and `C`s that we can compile that reproduce the problem too.

Comment: Check my answer, it includes link to complete solution in vs 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

You may download the whole solution (vs 2010) from this link: https://rapidshare.com/files/4269394110/ExtensionProblem.zip.

I found the complete answer thanks to @Rick Sladkey whose answer was almost complete. The only thing that causes the code to always fail to compile is a constraint on generic method in project B that is specified using class from project C.

Ok, here is the listing:

**PROJECT A**

ClassA.cs

```
using B;

namespace A
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.ExtMethodC();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the code to compile comment first line (`using B;`).

Here is a class that includes random extension method in project A.

ExtensionsA.cs

```
namespace A
{
    public static class ExtensionsA
    {
        public static void ExtMethodC(this int[] a)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**PROJECT B**

Extensions.cs - this class has method with generic constraint `T : ClassC`

```
using C;

namespace B
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string ExtMethodB<T>(this T cInstance) where T : ClassC
        {
            return cInstance.Foo;
        }
    }
}
```

**PROJECT C**

ClassC.cs - we need this class to use it in extension method in project B

```
namespace C
{
    public class ClassC
    {
        public string Foo;
    }
}
```

For me it looks like a bug in compiler that is too eager to check if extension method in project B may be used in project A.

Thanks for all your answers! Especially @Rick Sladkey.

Comment: Interesting puzzle!  Be sure to report it at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: If you are interested, here is a link to my report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/668498/problem-with-extension-method-in-c-compiler

Comment: Thanks for reporting that.  Although it is closed as "Won't Fix", that saved me a lot of headache. :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a small example that reproduces the problem.  It is caused by an extension method in B that uses types defined in C in its signature.  Even though the extension method is not used, the error is triggered by the process of searching all extension methods that are accessible via usings.

ConsoleApplicationA.cs:

```
using ClassLibraryB;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static int Test(this int a)
        {
            return a;
        }
    }

    public class ProgramA
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            0.Test();
        }
    }
}
```

ClassLibraryB.cs:

```
using ClassLibraryC;

namespace ClassLibraryB
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static ClassC Test(this ClassB b)
        {
            return new ClassC();
        }
    }

    public class ClassB
    {
    }
}
```

ClassLibraryC.cs:

```
namespace ClassLibraryC
{
    public class ClassC
    {
    }
}
```

This test case produces this error:

> error CS0012: The type 'ClassLibraryC.ClassC' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ClassLibraryC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

**Edit:**

In my **opinion**, this is a bug in the C# compiler, because it very surprising behavior for a method you did not reference to cause your program to fail to compile.  The C# compiler team may have a different opinion.

In the meantime, a workaround is to place your extension methods in B that use types from C in their signature into a separate namespace and add a using to that namespace only when the calling assembly has a reference to both B and C.  Alternatively if the number of offending extension methods is small and their value is limited you might be able to move or remove them.  Finally, and most obviously, you can be done with it and simply add the reference to C that it tells you you should add.

**Second edit:**

Caveat: I just reviewed this to clean up the example and it is weaker than I had thought.  It only fails if the name of the called extension method in A exactly matches the name of the uncalled extension method in B.  So for example if you rename `Test` in B to `NotCalled` it no longer fails, yet in the original problem, presumably it would.

**Final edit:**

With collaboration we narrowed down the necessary conditions to reproduce the issue described in the original question: an extension method in B with types from C in its signature that use a generic type constraint.  The above test case is a narrower example.  The specific conditions are clearly related to the specific implementation of the way the compiler searches for extension methods.

In summary, references are a run-time feature and extension methods are a compile-time feature.  No matter how the error message is generated, if the method is not called, the **compiler is the one who desires the reference at compile-time, the assembly does not need the reference at run-time**.  Therefore the error is not one that the compiler has no choice but the emit, it's just an inconvenient situation for the compiler.

Comment: Yes, it would. It happens with my custom method and every extension method from Linq: Where, First, etc.

Comment: Check my UPDATE3 - I created completely random method name.

Comment: @empi: It's is very important to me if you can answer this question: are there extension methods in B that use types from C in their signatures?  Just use "Find in Files" -> "In Project Only" -> Search String: "(this " and then look for the type xxx in your original error message.

Comment: I found the complete answer - the problem was in generic constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer seems to me to be that there is an extension method on `IEnumerable` or `IEnumrable<T>` called `Where` in `B`. This extension method uses a type from `C` (as return type? or type constraint?) which requires you to reference it.

What does Visual Studio tell you `Where` is?

As for solution, it seems `B` is under your control, so you should delete the extension method, it really shouldn't be there. As an alternative solution, you can use the long syntax: `Enumerable.Where(collection, s => s != null)`.

Comment: It happens with my custom method and every extension method from Linq: Where, First, etc. so I don't think that's the case.